# Xamarin Android 9patch image files with .9 in filename give error when compiling

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I added `splash.9.png` to `drawable` folder, but it gives compilation error:

> Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1790,3): error MSB3375: The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.

It's clearly a problem with the file name, it doesn't like the `.9` in the filename.

If I remove the `.9` and just have `splash.png` in the filename, then it doesn't display the image using 9pach technique, the image is just stretched. I know the image works because it looks perfect in the preview in the draw-9-patch tool.

I'm confused, I can't be the only person with this problem.

I am using latest Android stable, and I am in VS 2017.

Comment: 9-patch image file should have extension .9 before .png, the error message suggests that your resource's name could be wrong. How did you use this 9-patch image file? I couldn't reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue when setting MSBuild to `Diagnostics` level. There was a problem in the 9patch image, even though the draw-9-patch tool didn't say anthing